# path to image is also plotted in pdf

Tags: pdf, export

I have the following problem: If I export the tex file to pdf, I get the figure but also the path written above it. How can I avoid this ?

```
  \documentclass{article}%
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
    \usepackage{lmodern}%
    \usepackage{textcomp}%
    \usepackage{lastpage}%
    \usepackage[head=1pt,margin=0.3in,bottom=0.3in,includeheadfoot=False]{geometry}%
    \usepackage{graphicx}%
    %
    \usepackage{helvet}%
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
    \usepackage{needspace}%
    \newcommand*\measurePage{\par\setlength{\measurepage}{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip}}%
    \usepackage{textcomp}%
    %
    \begin{document}%
    \normalsize%


    \begin{figure}[h!]%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C:/Users/EPFL/Google Drive/Mooc/Cellular Mechanisms of Brain Functions/Text And Slides/1/Slides/1.jpg}%
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the provided answer your question? If yes, then consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does happen if you specify file paths including spaces. You should enclose the path to the image in double quotes (`"`) leaving out the file extension:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[head=1pt,margin=0.3in,bottom=0.3in,includeheadfoot=False]{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
%
\usepackage{helvet}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{needspace}%
\newcommand*\measurePage{\par\setlength{\measurepage}{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip}}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%


\begin{figure}[h!]%
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"C:/Users/EPFL/Google Drive/Mooc/Cellular Mechanisms of Brain Functions/Text And Slides/1/Slides/1"}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If the file is in a subfolder of your main TeX file, it might be better to use the relative (space free) path. You could also consider adding that folder to your `\graphicspath` (I don't know how well this works for paths containing spaces).